# Having a List of an Abstract class in Java and needing to loop through the List

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, abstract, extends

I'm trying to move my code from c# to java and it's the first time i'm trying to write java code.

Firstly i noticed that a List<> in c# is not as a list in java where i had to use an arrayList instead so i just changed

```
List<Instruments> instruments = new List<Instruments>();
```

to

```
List<Instruments> instruments = new ArrayList<Instruments>();
```

and that solved that.

Later on in my program i have a for loop which runs though the List (of an abstract "Instruments" class) and compares an enum (saved in .type) value which all the subclasses have. I:E

```
public static int HowManyOfType(InstrumentType TP)
{
    int HowMany = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < instruments.Size(); i++)
    {
        if (instruments[i].type == TP)
        HowMany++;
    }
    return HowMany;
}
```

However i'm getting the message "Array Type expected".
This problem wouldn't occur in c# because the property is stored in the abstract class and it would just do the comparison without needing to know the type of subclass that was stored.
I'm guessing that it's not that simple in java. Is there a was around this?
Thanks

Comment: Java doesn't have overloaded operators.

Comment: Collections are not arrays and you can not access elements with `[]`. You need to use `get()`. You should also check simplified *foreach* iteration via `for (Foo item : collection) {}`.

Comment: I would warn you about using `==` with `Object`. You should be defining `equals` and `hashCode` methods and using the `equals` method to check to equality. `==` doesn't do what you think it does - it checks referential equality - i.e. whether the two object references point to the same memory.

Comment: @BoristheSpider At least from how I'm reading the question, `TP` and `.type` are enum values, so `==` should work "correctly" in this case. You are correct in warning OP though.

Comment: Also, Java has different naming conventions than C#. Variables and methods in Java always start with a lowercase letter. Please respect these conventions if you don't want to be assassinated by one of your collegues.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
 if (instruments[i].type == TP)
```

to

```
 if (instruments.get(i).type == TP)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change  your for loop to this.

```
for (Instruments eachInstrument : instruments) {
    if (eachInstrument.type == TP) {
        howMany++;
    }
}
```

although without knowing what the data type of `eachInstrument.type` is, I can't be sure that it's correct to use `==`.  You may need to change this to `eachInstrument.type.equals(TP)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are used to C# you might find lambdas in Java 8 more natural.

```
long howMany = instruments.stream().filter(t -> t.type == TP).count();
```

Unless the type is a primitive or an Enum you may need to use equals

```
long howMany = instruments.stream().filter(t -> t.type.equals(TP)).count();
```